# Unable to run Kotlin scratch file

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

In a newly installed IntelliJ IDEA, I created a new Kotlin scratch file and tried to run it, but it gives me an error:

```
add kotlin script runtime jar to classpath
```

[image]

Comment: And what happens if you press <ENTER> to apply the suggestion from your IDE? If this not works, choose a module from "Use classpath of module" and press <Run> again.

Comment: no script runtime was found in the classpath: class kotline.script.templat.standard.scriptTemplatewithArgs not fpund.
please add kotling.script,runtime.jar to the module dependency.

where to found this kotline.script.runtime.jar might solve my problem.

Use classpath for module is useful, when i wanna use classes of those module, doing thay didn't help me.

Comment: Normally the Kotlin runtime is part of the module classpath and therfore should solve the problem. This means that the module also hasn't the Kotlin runtime configured.

Answer (score 7):

There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33010
As a workaround you could add kotlin runtime manually:

1. Open "Project Structure | Modules"
2. Select your module, click on plus and add "Kotlin" facet
3. See "kotlin library not found ..." message and click on "Fix..."
4. Select your module in editor ( "Use casspath of module").

Comment: when working with `build.gradle.kts` you add `implementation(kotlin("script-runtime"))` to your dependencies

Comment: Also, in a multiplatform project, the dependency mentioned by tango24 will not work in `commonMain`, but must be applied to `jvmMain`.

Answer (score 7):

Just add one line of dependency

```
dependencies {...implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.5.21")...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's any magical trick that sorted this out, but I **simply created** a new Scratch file and everything worked!

> PS: In my case, I suspect the problem was related to me renaming the scratch file previously. Again, not sure! :)

Comment: Seems related to [this bug](https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server/issues/178)